# What does < or > mean in python while comparing strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have written this code in python 3.5

```
x="absx"
o="abcdef"
```

and if i am doing this operation,

```
x<o
False   #it return's False and i think it should return True
```

So what is `'<'` doing in case of strings and why is it not returning true. 
how is it comparing x and o?

Comment: Strings are compared by the order they would appear in a regular  dictionary. Your `o` string would be before your `x` string in a dictionary, so `o < x` is True. See [Lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<` or `>` would result in lexicographic comparison of the two strings:

```
>>> x="absx"
>>> o="abcdef"
>>> x > o
True
```

Lexicographic ordering is same as dictionary ordering, and basically, the operators are checking for which string would come earlier (or later) in a dictionary order. The behavior is same for both Python 2 and 3.

The final result does not depend on the size of the string, Example:

```
>>> "a" < "aaaaa" 
True
```

In example above `"a"` would come before `"aaaaa"` when written in dictionary order. To compare by length of strings, use the `len()` function on the strings.

Comment: So it does not depend on the size of the string.

Comment: @Cedric The result is independent of size of strings, yes.

Comment: ' "absx"<"abcdef" '  returns  false   and  ' "abcdef" > "absx" ' returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Lexicographic comparison. In your case `o` would come after `x`.